# Identifying the EINVAL in a Kernel Control ctl_enqueuedata call

Tags: macos, kernel, kernel-module, kernel-extension

I want to send messages from a kernel extension into a userland program using kernel controls. I'm experiencing an `EINVAL` error when calling `ctl_enqueuedata`.

---

I've set up a Kernel Control and I'm trying to send messages through it using `ctl_enqueuedata`. I'm setting

```
ep_ctl.ctl_flags = 0
```

before passing to `ctl_register`, which, [the documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/NKEConceptual/control/control.html) suggest, should result in `ctl_unit` being automatically set.

To quote `kern_control.h`:

> For a dynamically assigned control ID, do not set the CTL_FLAG_REG_ID_UNIT flag.

```
static struct kern_ctl_reg ep_ctl;
static kern_ctl_ref kctlref;
```

...

```
errno_t error;
bzero(&ep_ctl, sizeof(ep_ctl));  // sets ctl_unit to 0
ep_ctl.ctl_id = 0;
ep_ctl.ctl_unit = 0;
strncpy(ep_ctl.ctl_name, CONTROL_NAME, strlen(CONTROL_NAME));
ep_ctl.ctl_flags = 0x0; // not CTL_FLAG_REG_ID_UNIT so unit gets supplied. Not CTL_FLAG_PRIVILEGED either.
ep_ctl.ctl_send = EPHandleSend;
ep_ctl.ctl_getopt = EPHandleGet;
ep_ctl.ctl_setopt = EPHandleSet;
ep_ctl.ctl_connect = EPHandleConnect;
ep_ctl.ctl_disconnect = EPHandleDisconnect;
error = ctl_register(&ep_ctl, &kctlref);

printf("setupControl %d\n", error);
```

When I call `ctl_register` it returns `0` ok.

When I call `ctl_enqueuedata`, passing in my `struct kern_ctl_reg` I'm getting 22, which is `EINVAL`. One of those arguments appears to be incorrect. The other arguments I'm passing are a static test string and its length for data, and zero flags.

```
int result = ctl_enqueuedata(kctlref, ep_ctl.ctl_unit, filename, length, 0x0);
```

The value of my `ep_ctl`'s `.ctl_unit` is `0`, the value of `.ctl_id` is `6`. Could it be that the `ctl_unit` value being passed to `ctl_enqueuedata` is invalid / un-initialized?

`kern_control.h` says of ctl_unit:

> This field is ignored for a dynamically assigned control ID

Which suggests that it isn't required anyway?

Have I missed something in initializing my ep_ctl?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you supply wrong value as the 2nd parameter of `ctl_enqueuedata()`. Instead of `ep_ctl.ctl_unit`, you have to remember `struct sockaddr_ctl::sc_unit` in the `EPHandleConnect()` callback and that's what you are supposed to pass into `ctl_enqueuedata()`.

Comment: Aha! I'll have a look next time I am looking at this code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using OSX's kernel debugging facilities to figure out what's going on here. That will let you walk through the relevant kernel code, and should tell you where it's rejecting your input.